# The Best way to use table with Specflow

Tags: selenium, bdd, specflow

My question is about the best practices with BDD(Specflow).
In the webapplication that i'm testing, I have to write a feature about creation of a contract.

To create a contract, user must pass By 8 Tabs and for each tab user will enter more than 15 values (Min 4, max 40 values).

**My proposition is**:

```
Given Go to the screen "Contrats"
    And Click on the button "New contract"
    When Enter in Tab1 
    | Field1     | Field2      | Field3    |
    | -----------| ------------| ----------|
    And Click on the Next button
    And Enter in Tab2
    | Field1          | Field2     |
    | --------------- | -----------|
    And Click on the Next button
    And Enter in Tab3
    | Field1 | Field2 | Field 3| Field4   | Field5    | Field6 |Field7           |
    | -------| -------| ------ | -------- | --------- | -------| ----------------|
    And Click on the Next button
    And Enter in Tab4
     | Field1 | Field2 | Field 3| Field4   | Field5    | Field6 |Field7          | Field8|
    | -------| -------| ------ | -------- | --------- | -------| ----------------| ------|
    And Click on the Next button 
    And Enter in Tab5
    | Field1 | Field2 | Field 3| Field4   | Field5    | Field6 
    | -------| -------| ------ | -------- | --------- | -------|
    And Click on the Next button
    And Enter in Tab6
    | Field1     | Field2      | Field3    |
    | -----------| ------------| ----------|

    And Click on the Next button
    And Click on the Next button
    And Cliquer sur Oui
    And Enter in Tab7
    | Field1     | Field2      | 
    | -----------| ------------| 
    And Click on confirm enregistration
    And Save the contract reference and close the popup
    And Click on button No
    Then Redirecting the Summary tab
```

So in this Case for each Tab i must have model for exemple:

```
  public class Tab1{ 
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
  public string Field3 { get; set; }
  }
```

**Question:** 
In this feature i'm try to enter only the mandatory fields.
But in other features i have to enter sometimes more fields so in Tab1 I will enter for example 37 fields. 
What I can do in this case:

**1-**
Create another model?: I will have too much models

**2-**
Create just one model with max of fields, and for the first situation I will set an empty value for other fiels (Field4-> Field37) : Too much attributes for a model.

**3-** for each bloc of Tab1 we create Class like :

```
  public Class Tab1{

  public Bloc1 Field1 { get; set; }
  public Bloc2 Field2 { get; set; }
  public Bloc3 Field3 { get; set; }


  public class Bloc1{ 
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
  public string Field3 { get; set; }
  }

  public Class Bloc2{
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
  public string Field3 { get; set; }
  }
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

But with this solution How I can write my feature?!

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue with my test data. I need to pass 20 to 30 fields for each test as it contains end to end workflow. It would be very difficult if you use tables as you need create table class for each set of input values (in your case Tab1, Tab2, etc.)

You can use **Scenatio Outline** rather than **Scenario** to pass the input values. See below example:

```
# Basic Login check
# Verifies whether user is able to login or not
Scenario Outline: REG - Login Check
Given I have logged in using "<username>" and "<password>"
When I should see my username after login
Then I will logout of Echo
Examples:
| username         | password         |Field1|Field2|Field3|Field4|Field5|
| lee kirby-walker | LKirby-Walker10* |input1|input2|input3|input4|input5|
| sample 1         | pwd1             |input6|input7|input8|input9|input10|
```

You can pass any number of rows of test data to the test. But it create those many test cases in VS. These test data values will be passed to the step definition methods as parameters.

See below step definition for step *Given I have logged in using "username" and "password"*

```
        [Given(@"I have logged in using ""(.*)"" and ""(.*)""")]
        public void LogInUsingUsernameAndPassword(string userName, string password)
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current["userName"] = userName;
            UserHomePage = LoginPage.Login(userName, password);
            Reporter.ReportNote(string.Format("User {0} logged in successfully", userName), Status.Pass);
        }
```

But with **Scenario Outline** you must use **Examples** otherwise specflow will throw an error.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem, because here i'm not trying to test something with a multiple examples, but this just one example but the web page that i have to test contains multiple fields. But what you talk about is i have just 2 fields username and passwor and i want to test just those two fields with multiple examples.

Comment: What I have provided is just an example. You can add as many test data fields as you want. Like username and password, you can add Field1, Field2, Field3.. etc. I have used 20+ fields to my tests. If you want you can use different sets of test data for the same test. Just use one set if don't.

Comment: Also the same problem, here how you will implement the solution, this step.In my case i'm not seraching to use **Examples** just one row but the problem that i faced is after that when i will implement this solution i'm obliged to use a list with 5 fields my problem is with the number of fiels and not the inputs.

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong. In Scenario Outline you are not obliged to use specific number of variables. You can provide as many test fields as you want for scenario because they will be passed as parameters to the step definition (see my example above). But for step you have to use specified number of input fields. For step Given I have logged in using "username" and "password" in above example you can always pass only two fields.